# C: Problem with initializing array values to zero

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to construct the following 14*14 array i C: [I 0; 0 -I], that is a 7*7 identity matrix upper left, minus the identity lower right and zeros otherwise.

This is the method:

```
#define DIM 7

 double S[2*DIM][2*DIM];

 for(i = 0; i < DIM; i++){
     for(j = 0; j < DIM; j++){
         if(i == j){
             S[i][j] = 1.0;
             S[i+7][j+7] = -1.0;
         }
         else{
             S[i][j] = 0.0;
         }
     } 
 }
```

This works fine for all the diagonal elements; however, some elements of the array get initialized to crazy values; for example, `13,6` gets initialized to

68111186113812079535019899599437200576833320031036694798491976301968333351950125611739840800974137748034248687763243996679617222196278187875968953700681881752083957666277350377710107236511681624408064.000000

This seems to be happening consistently (at least thrice) to entries `11,13`, `12,9`, `12,10`, `13,12` and `13,6`.

Can anybody tell me what's at play here or provide an alternative solution?

Cheers!

EDIT: The weird entries aren't consistent.

EDIT2: Typo: `13,12`, not `13,15`

Comment: How are you getting `13,15` with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop only covers the upper left quadrant, so the off-diagonal elements in the other quadrants are not initialized and contain garbage. Your loop should go up to `2*DIM` for each dimension, so that the off-diagonal elements are zeroed, and then your conditional for the diagonal elements should just be a little more complex to decide which value to set the diagonal element to.

Note that [13, 15] is entirely outside of this array!

Comment: Of course. I'm not feeling too smart now, let me tell you that ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can initialize the whole array with zeros, then set only the diagonal

```
double S[2*DIM][2*DIM] = {0};
for (i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
    s[i][i] = 1;
    s[i + DIM][i + DIM] = -1;
}
```

Comment: ITYM `double S[2*DIM][2*DIM] = { { 0 } };`

Comment: @Paul: your version may be more explicit, but `= {0}` "works" for initializing anything -- eg `int k = {0};`, `struct whatever obj[2][15] = {0};`, .... I like to call it **the universal zero initializer** :-)

Comment: It may *work*, but it generates warnings from gcc with -Wall: `warning: missing braces around initializer` `warning: (near initialization for ‘S[0]’)`

Comment: Yep ... `gcc` can be too helpful sometimes. I have `-Wno-missing-braces` added to my gcc alias because of that.

Comment: 6.7.8/19 in [n1256.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf): "... all subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized implicitly ..."

Comment: Each to their own - I still prefer the more explicit `{ { 0 } }` for a 2D array, and it helps too when you work somewhere that requires clean compilation with `gcc -Wall`.

Answer (score 2):

You are never writing to `s[i][j]` for `i != j` and `i >= DIM` or `j >= DIM`. If your array has automatic storage (is "local") it contains arbitrary init values.

Comment: It would contain garbage if it were `malloc`ed as well.

Comment: Yes, but it isn't malloced: `double S[2*DIM][2*DIM];`

Comment: My point is that *however* it were to be allocated -- on the stack, or on the heap -- it contains garbage, so that most of your second sentence is redundant. The fact that it's automatic is immaterial.

Comment: Sorry, I was taught variables (and arrays) with static storage are initialized to 0 automatically. Is this not true?

Answer (score 1):

I would say most of the elements that are outside 7x7 will not be initialized at all unless i == j (diagonal elements).

What do you want to initialize them to?

Answer (score 1):

That's because your not initializing those elements. Here is some better code:

```
#define DIM 14

double S[DIM][DIM];

for (i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < DIM; j++) {
        if (i == j) {
            if (i < 7) {
                S[i][j] = 1.0;
            } else {
                S[i][j] = -1.0;
            }
        } else {
            S[i][j] = 0.0;
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize values with an i or j between DIM + 1 and 2*DIM.  So when you look at a value stored in one of those positions, you see whatever was there before that space was accessed by your matrix.